# Picture Color Filters Harmonizing: Web (CSS, SVG), Snapseed, Print (GIMP/Photoshop)

Tags: css, svg, photoshop, gimp, inkscape

In the past years multiple times I had difficulty to harmonize color filters (mainly desaturize, slight hue change, sometimes sepia or duotone, etc.) for Corporate Image Style purposes by using:

- **CSS**: easy filter method for images in the web (limited)
- **SVG**: advanced pics & graphics & filters edited in Inkscape (both for Web and Print use)
- For **Printing (CMYK)** as a final target filters in GIMP or to hand
  over to third party in Photoshop would complete the harmonizing.

I would be happy if I could convert/use CSS filters easily in Inkscape (it is possible but not easy) and to use them in Android-Snapseed, GIMP and Photoshop. I must admit I'm not an expert in GIMP and Photoshop. I could not find discussions about this exact topic. Example CSS Code:

`filter: sepia(0.9) hue-rotate(-17deg) saturate(0.75) contrast(1.1) brightness(1.1)`

Beside doing all by manual harmonizing just with the own eye has anyone the same problem and a more consistent method achieving exactly (or almost) the same color filters on the different output formats?

Comment: Are you aware of this [equivalency list](https://www.w3.org/TR/filter-effects-1/#ShorthandEquivalents) between CSS and SVG filters?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ccprog: yes, but AFAIk it is mostly manual code copy and paste and even direct SVG-Edit, so no easy in Inkscape filter application. I forgot to mention Snapseed which I use on the Smartphone. Would change to another FOSS/Free Option if CSS/SVG-Filters would be supported (or an easy conversion possible).

Comment: Inkscape filters are SVG filters. The inkscape filter editor is a fair visualization of the underlying XML code, but you can also edit or compare their relation with the inbuilt XML editor.